# MySQL LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY and ORDER BY not working as required

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
'products' => ('product_id', 'name', 'description')
```

and a table

```
'product_price' => ('product_price_id', 'product_id', 'price', 'date_updated')
```

I want to perform a query something like

```
SELECT `p`.*, `pp`.`price` 
FROM `products` `p` 
LEFT JOIN `product_price` `pp` ON `pp`.`product_id` = `p`.`product_id`
GROUP BY `p`.`product_id` 
ORDER BY `pp`.`date_updated` DESC
```

As you can probably guess the price changes often and I need to pull out the latest one. The trouble is I cannot work out how to order the LEFT JOINed table. I tried using some of the GROUP BY functions like MAX() but that would only pull out the column not the row.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you would like to happen? Do you want to order by the max of the group? Do you want to join only with the latest update? Perhaps some example data and the expected output for that data would help clarify your question.

Comment: I have one product with 5 different prices which different 'date_updated' datetimes. I need to join and pull out the latest price.

Comment: This is a simplification of a much larger query. I cannot use an INNER JOIN because in the real query I join to many tables and use an IF to select the NOT NULL column.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears that it is **impossible** to use an ORDER BY on a GROUP BY summarisation. My fundamental logic is flawed. I will need to run the following subquery.

```
SELECT `p`.*, `pp`.`price` FROM `products` `p` 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `price` FROM `product_price` ORDER BY `date_updated` DESC
) `pp` 
ON `p`.`product_id` = `pp`.`product_id`
GROUP BY `p`.`product_id`;
```

This will take a performance hit but as it is the same subquery for each row it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I asked a similar question just now and got this response from @Gordon Linoff http://stackoverflow.com/a/18763815/570796

Answer (score 2):

You need to set aliases properly I think and also set what you are joining on:

```
SELECT p.*, pp.price 
FROM products AS p 
LEFT JOIN product_price AS pp
ON pp.product_id = p.product_id 
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY pp.date_updated DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed the ON part. I have edited my query. I believe the AS part is optional.

Answer (score -1):

This will give you the last updated price:

```
select
  p.*, pp.price
from
  products p,
  -- left join this if products may not have an entry in prodcuts_price
  -- and you would like to see a null price with the product
  join 
  (
      select 
        product_price_id, 
        max(date_updated) 
      from products_price
      group by product_price_id
   ) as pp_max
    on p.product_id = pp.product_id
  join products_price pp on 
    pp_max.prodcuts_price_id = pp.products_price_id
```

Comment: This would probably work however I would really like to avoid doing a subquery as I have a large dataset.

Comment: Thats way the way that gives correct results. Other queries will give **all** prices. But hey if they work faster just use that right ...?@!

Comment: I appreciate your help but my query doesn't give all prices, it just gives me a random price which I hope to resolve by ordering correctly.

Comment: group by strategy is wrong and will fail. ordering happens after rows are selected. If speed is paramount denormalize your table and add a boolean price_current field into products_price that keeps track of what one you want. If you dont believe me, repost this again where it is more explicit with what you want.

Comment: @Simon, even with analytics (if only MySQL supported them) -- you'd still need a subquery.

Comment: what's the output of this? `(select product_price_id, max(date_updated) from products_price)` will undownvote if the logic/intent is clear. looks like wrong answer

Comment: The output is the most recent id and date that the price is updated. Whats unclear??? seems obvious. There are many prices. Only one is current. That current one is the most recent one. We need to know this to get current pricing. Once we have that id we can join the full table. There is no way to do this without a separate aggregate.

Comment: on which group MAX is evaluating its aggregation? why there is no GROUP BY?

Comment: and your sub-query returns one row only, each product's price is updated on different dates. why only return one row?  there's something wrong with your query's logic

Comment: see my answer, how i simplify your answer (at the last part) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580479/mysql-left-join-group-by-and-order-by-not-working-as-required/4581849#4581849

Answer (score -2):

Mysqlism:

```
SELECT p.*, MAX(pp.date_updated), pp.price 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN product_price pp ON pp.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Will work on some RDBMS:

```
SELECT p.*, pp.date_updated, pp.price 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN product_price pp ON pp.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE (p.product_id, pp.date_updated) 

   in (select product_id, max(date_updated) 
       from product_price 
       group by product_id)
```

Will work on most RDBMS:

```
SELECT p.*, pp.date_updated, pp.price 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN product_price pp ON pp.product_id = p.product_id

WHERE EXISTS
(
    select null -- inspired by Linq-to-SQL style :-)
    from product_price 

    WHERE product_id = p.product_id 

    group by product_id

    HAVING max(date_updated) = pp.date_updated
)
```

Will work on all RDBMS:

```
SELECT p.*, pp.date_updated, pp.price 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN product_price pp ON pp.product_id = p.product_id

LEFT JOIN 
(
    select product_id, max(date_updated) as recent 
    from product_price 
    group by product_id
) AS latest 
ON latest.product_id = p.product_id AND latest.recent = pp.date_updated
```

And if **nate c**'s code intent is to just get one row from product_price, no need to **table-derive** (i.e. `join (select product_price_id, max(date_updated) from products_price) as pp_max`), he might as well just simplify(i.e. no need to use the product_price_id surrogate primary key) it like the following:

```
SELECT p.*, pp.date_updated, pp.price 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN product_price pp ON pp.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE pp.date_updated = (select max(date_updated) from product_price)
```

Comment: Your Mysqlism does not work. That is the whole the point of this post. The price that is selected does not **have to** although it may pick the price that coincides with the max date. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: The last query has nothing to do with my intent.

Comment: That's the point, u lack the GROUP BY clause in your subquery; so naturally it will pick up one row only. Then u add a GROUP BY on your subquery, using the product_price_id; I can hazard a guess that the product_price_id is a surrogate primary key, and what's more, it's a sequential id, whatdyathink? Why use GROUP BY on unique on each row on one table? it's absurd. Regarding Mysqlism, I'm not sure of my answer on that, I don't have MySQL on my box, I thought MySQL GROUP BY has super powers, I thought it has Postgresql's DISTINCT ON functionality, your first answer lead me to that thinking :-/

Comment: Maybe you should put MySQL on your box instead of just making up answers for MySQL questions!

Comment: I know MySQL before, and I know some of many(correct) MySQLism. And your reference on GROUP BY without other fields, I know it very well, and in fact, Postgresql is embracing it, with a twist, Postgresql do it in a controlled manner(Postgres is still disciplined) http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/08/08/waiting-for-9-1-recognize-functional-dependency-on-primary-keys/

Comment: It's only in this answer I'm mislead by someone's answer, you said that your subquery return row**s**, based on that I assumed MySQL MAX aggregation **can** pick up its corresponding row, that MySQL MAX can somehow mimic Postgresql DISTINCT ON, basing on your answer it looks like it is. Then when I answer in the same manner(MySQLism), you said it's not correct