# Should I create a new field in the table or just select the MAX of the second table

Tags: mysql, join

[On this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15249486/1624960) I received an answer that worked well. I am now wondering if there is a possible better structure.

I have two tables.

```
Projects : id, title
Status : project_id, status_id, created(DATETIME)
```

At the moment to get the status of my project, I get the project ID and pull the latest row out of the status table based on the project id. To get this latest row is quite a hassle.

Should I rather change the schema to this?

```
Projects : id, title, current_status_id(FK)
Status : id(PK), project_id, status_id, created(DATETIME)
```

Then I can just join the tables with the FK and get the row that I want without looking for the latest?

**EDIT**:

So I want something like this

```
SELECT * FROM projects
LEFT JOIN status on projects.id = status.project_id
WHERE projects.id = 1
```

But I want only the latest record in the status table.

**EDIT 2**:

So I want something like this

```
SELECT * FROM projects
LEFT JOIN status on projects.id = status.project_id
```

But for each project returned, only get the latest status record for that project_id from status.

Answer (score 1):

How is this a hassle?

```
SELECT project_id, status_id, created 
FROM Status 
WHERE project_id = the-id
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Or, if you need a list of multiple projects:

```
SELECT a.project_id, a.status_id, a.created 
FROM Status a
LEFT JOIN Status b
ON a.project_id = b.project_id
AND b.created > a.created
WHERE a.project_id IN(id1, id2, id3) AND b.project_id IS NULL;
```

So, with project data:

```
SELECT Projects.*, Status.*
FROM Projects
LEFT JOIN Status 
ON Status.project_id = Projects.id
WHERE Projects.id = the-id
ORDER BY Status.created DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Or:

```
SELECT Projects.*, Status.*
FROM Projects
LEFT JOIN Status a
ON a.project_id = Projects.id
LEFT JOIN Status b
ON a.project_id = b.project_id
AND b.created > a.created
WHERE b.project_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: That would be using a seperate query. I would like one query joined for speed

Comment: Does not compute? Both are single queries for different purposes (so you need only 1 of your choice), and 'one query joined for speed' => I don't get what you mean with that.

Comment: I would love to select the project and have the status come up in that query. Is that not quicker then performing two queries?

Comment: So, you mean you have to select the project by other means then a project id? Just join the project table to it then & add the clauses, no biggie?

Comment: yes - i'm pretty sure OP intends to join this current status to the main record. (agreed not a big thing)

Comment: And BTW: although it can probably be done in 1 here, 2 queries _can_ be faster then one. Don't fall into the trap of trying to cram everything in a single call.

Comment: @Randy and Wrikken, see edit. You think maybe better in to calls then?

Comment: @Wrikken yeah, you are right, but that doesnt let me select all projects without knowing thier IDs. How to do it for mulitple

Comment: Give an example where and how you select multiple projects, and I'll add it in for you.

Answer (score 1):

That's one way to do it.

You might not even need the current_status field to be an FK; why not just store the value?  You could get into odd circular references otherwise.

Another way would be to store a status archive, separate of the projects table.  Every time the status changes, insert the current status into the archive table, and change the projects.status value.

Comment: Your second option is what I meant

Comment: use a trigger to populate the status history table. then only deal with the main table in general.