# How to join two tables with group by and order by in MySQLi?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables with the following structure. I want to display a list of data from both tables but the list should be ordered by `T_id` and grouped by `U_id`.

User

**U_id - Name - Pic**

Topic

**T_id - U_id   - title - content   - date**

Output

**T_id  - U_id  - title - content   - date  - Name  - Pic**

I don't know how to do that using MySQL or MySQLi, I tried several times but I was unsuccessful. If anyone can give me an idea it will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.T_id, t.U_id ,t.title, t.content, t.date, u.Name, u.Pic FROM Topic t
LEFT JOIN User u ON u.U_id = t.U_id 
GROUP BY u.U_id
ORDER BY t.T_id DESC
```

Comment: I knew this , but still not working ... actually all users have topics and users may have many topics I want to display one topic per user but the newest topic and the order of the list should be by topic id as desc, can you help please

Comment: what does it display??

Comment: it displays the list but ordered by U_ID instead of T_ID

Comment: If that does not work then try using `join` instead of `left join`

Comment: I tried both left join and join with your updated sql but still not working , what do you think ? don't you think I have something wrong in my data ?

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762726/mysql-join-group-by-order-by/18763815#18763815

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by U_id will have no effect unless you have a large amount of duplicate times that the same user has the same Topic on the same day - I suspect you are trying to ask a different question than what you have articulated.

Comment: thank you for the reply, actually users may have may topics I want to display one topic per user but the newest topic and the order should be by topic desc