# Laravel ordering results of a left join

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by, left-join, eloquent

I am trying to replicate the below SQL in Laravels Eloquent query builder.

```
select a.name, b.note from projects a 
left join (select note, project_id from projectnotes order by created_at desc) as b on     (b.project_id = a.id) 
where projectphase_id = 10 group by a.id;
```

So far I have:

```
$projects = Project::leftjoin('projectnotes', function($join)
{
  $join->on('projectnotes.project_id', '=', 'projects.id');
})
->where('projectphase_id', '=', '10')
->select(array('projects.*', 'projectnotes.note as note'))
->groupBy('projects.id')
->get()
```

which works for everything except getting the most recent projectnotes, it just returns the first one entered into the projectnotes table for each project.

I need to get the order by 'created_at' desc into the left join but I don't know how to achieve this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need subquery. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580479/mysql-left-join-group-by-and-order-by-not-working-as-required

Comment: Yes, there is a subquery already in the Laravel code but I don't know how to add the order by into it. I get a parse error when I try $join->orderBy('creted_at', 'DESC')

Comment: No, there is no subquery. You just join a table, while you need to join a sub select instead. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079281/laravel-fluent-query-builder-join-with-subquery

Comment: this package can help you a look https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-eloquent-join

Answer (score 5):

Your subquery is unnecessary and is just making the entire thing inefficient.  To be sure though, make sure this query returns the same results...

```
SELECT
    projects.name,
    notes.note
FROM
    projects
LEFT JOIN
    projectnotes notes on projects.id = notes.project_id
WHERE
    projects.projectphase_id = 10
ORDER BY
    notes.created_at desc
```

If it does, that query translated to the query builder looks like this...

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')
    ->select('projects.name', 'notes.note')
    ->join('projectnotes as notes', 'projects.id', '=', 'notes.project_id', 'left')
    ->where('projects.projectphase_id', '=', '10')
    ->orderBy('notes.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: This is completely different query that returns all the rows from joined table instead of just a single, latest one. The subquery is necessary for this.